# Converting an array of 2 consecutive bytes to integers faster

Tags: c#, .net, mono, boo

I have a 'huge' amount of data, which may vary between 50 and 100 MegaBytes.
I read this data in as an array of bytes using a filestreamer.

The thing is, I want to convert all consecutive 2 bytes into an integer.
The way I do this is I loop through the array of bytes with a stepsize of two, and then use BitConvert to do the conversion:

```
_data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(soundData[i : i + 2], 0) // Convert 2 bytes into an int and store at i
```

So each two bytes get turned into an Int16.
The problem however, is that this is too slow, as for a file of about 50 megabytes this can take up 20 seconds!

Is there a generic way of doing this instantly, instead of calling this function on each 2 bytes of my data array such that it isn't that slow? Preferably in a 'safe' way, so no unsafe code.

Comment: "Fast"?  "Mono"?  http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

Comment: The whole point of a *stream* is to process the data while loading it, not to load it first and then iterate over it. Is the conversion really the bottleneck? Could you include the loop in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the array of bytes are in the correct Endian, then just allocate an Int16 array and use Buffer.Block copy (air code):

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
short[] s = new short[2]; // 4 bytes long
Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, s, 0, 4);
```

Comment: The endianness was indeed correct, and using this method my 50MB data was able to be converted in 1.5s instead of the 15-20s, which is a drastic improvement!

Answer (score 3):

Without testing, I'm not sure I have the math and "endianess" right, but the other option would be to try something like this:

```
// Convert 2 bytes into an int and store at i
_data[j] = (int)soundData[i] + (soundData[i + 1] << 8);
```

If that's also not fast enough, then you may need a different approach to the problem.

Some other ideas can be found for the question: [Convert Byte Array to Integer In VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227083/convert-byte-array-to-integer-in-vb-net)

Comment: Probably will need a cast before shifting.

Comment: Added, although I'm not sure exactly what type of integer he's converting to.